# Is Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity properly COM-registered?

Tags: .net, com, com-interop

I'm trying to use the `Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity` library to talk to a windows phone 7 device, but whenever I try to create a `DatastoreManager` (which is the first step) I get a COMException about guid {250BEABB-55E8-43BB-AC97-2D95674ECE14} (which corresponds to the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.DeviceConnectivity.Interop.ConManClass` type) not being registered. Is the smartdevice framework properly COM-registered? What's going on?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem because my app was targeting AnyCPU (on a 64-bit machine). Try targeting your application for the x86 platform - it worked for me.